# Using AutoFac to create a collection of objects of undefined length

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am getting some quotes from a third party provider. I am transfering the quotes to my local object but need advice on how to create a new quote object for the list where you dont know how many quotes you'll need in the constructor

I tried this

```
 public class ConvertThirdPartyQuoteToLocalQuote
    {
        private readonly IQuote quote;

        public ConvertThirdPartyQuoteToLocalQuote(IQuote quote)
        {
            this.quote = quote;
        }

        public IQuote ConvertToDomainQuote(List<ThirdPartyQuote> thirdPartyQuotes)
        {
            var response = new List<IQuote>();

            foreach (var thirdPartyQuote in thirdPartyQuotes)
            {
                quote.Price = thirdPartyQuote.Price;
                quote.Description = thirdPartyQuote.Price; 
                response.Add(quote);
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

But it just over writes the same object.

I want to do some thing like this but dont know how,

```
    public class ConvertThirdPartyQuoteToLocalQuote
    {


        public IQuote ConvertToDomainQuote(List<ThirdPartyQuote> thirdPartyQuotes)
        {
            var response = new List<IQuote>();

            foreach (var thirdPartyQuote in thirdPartyQuotes)
            {

                // Use autofac to new up an instance in each loop 
                // or pass it through the constructor

                quote.Price = thirdPartyQuote.Price;
                quote.Description = thirdPartyQuote.Price;
                response.Add(quote);
            }

            return response; 
        }
    }
```

I don't really want to pollute my code with autofac code if I can avoid it so passing the object through the constructor would be preferable but am willing to compromise

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a dependency on the container by using **delegate injection**.

```
public class ConvertThirdPartyQuoteToLocalQuote
{
    private readonly Func<IQuote> quoteBuilder;

    public ConvertThirdPartyQuoteToLocalQuote(
        Func<IQuote> quoteBuilder)
    {
        this.quoteBuilder = quoteBuilder;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IQuote> ConvertToDomainQuote(
        IEnumerable<ThirdPartyQuote> thirdPartyQuotes)
    {
        foreach (var thirdPartyQuote in thirdPartyQuotes)
        {
            IQuote quote = this.quoteBuilder();
            quote.Price = thirdPartyQuote.Price;
            quote.Description = thirdPartyQuote.Price;
            yield return quote;
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration looks like this:

```
var mainBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
mainBuilder.RegisterType<IQuote>().As<Quote>();
mainBuilder.Register((c, p) => 
    new ConvertThirdPartyQuoteToLocalQuote(() => c.Resolve<IQuote>()));
IContainer container = mainBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: What could I do if I wanted to pass a parameter into quoteBuilder() so that I could add into the constructor? eg  
      
    
            var someValue = "SomeValue";
    
            
                IQuote quote = this.quoteBuilder(someValue);

Comment: @user1838438 if you're wanting to pass something into the constructor then the `Container` should not be part of the equation. You should just `new` up a `Quote` object - try to restrict your use of the `Container` to service injection and not creating instances of `Dto` types.